# I had one job to do

Tags: c#, performance, linq

The code I am working with:

```
foreach(var currentJob in ttJobHead)
{
    foreach (var hdCase in Db.HDCase.Where(hdCase => hdCase.HDCaseNum == currentJob.HDCaseNum))
    {
        currentJob.ProjectID = hdCase.ProjectID;
    }
}
```

equivalent to the following pseudo code:

```
foreach(var t1Row in Table1)
{
    foreach (var t2Row in Table2.Where(r => r.Property1 == t1Row.Property1))
    {
        t1Row.Property2 = t2Row.Poperty2;
    }
}
```

I know for sure that the `Table1` will only ever have 1 row, therefore the outer `foreach` will only ever iterate once.

My question is is there any advantage storing reference to the `t1Row` in a variable rather having a `foreach` loop?

Comment: So `ttJobHead` is a DataTable ?

Comment: @Heslacher Looks to be that way.

Comment: @It'sbeenapleasure I made an edit to your post. Let me know if that improves it or roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: @Heslacher If you say so...

Comment: Please also give a more specific title based on the code's purpose.  Specific questions are just needed in the post body.

Comment: @200_success you had one job to do! One job!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would say yes, there is value in removing the foreach loop, because your code will more appropriately mirror what you're *expecting* to happen versus what *can* happen. It's unclear to someone looking at this code for the first time that you're really doing a lookup based on one value as opposed to a join.

I would go a step further than storing the reference to table 1. I would actually store the row and then query table 2 for matches, e.g.

```
var currentJob = ttJobHead.Single();
foreach(var hdCase in Db.HDCase.Where(hCase => hCase.HDCaseNum == currentJob.HDCaseNum))
{
    hdCase.ProjectID = currentJob.ProjectID;
}
```

Note that `Single()` aggressively throws an exception when there's not a matching row. That's a good thing in a lot of cases. It fails quickly as soon as your data model changes and also clearly states to developers "an empty table makes an exception throw. Don't support it unless you intend to change that requirement." Of course you can change what you support by changing the code to use `SingleOrDefault()`, `First()`, or `FirstOrDefault()`.

You could also merge the assignment statement into the foreach statement but it could make tracking exceptions more difficult.

I also noticed you mentioned in a comment that you intend to only find one matching record. If that is the case then remove the second foreach loop, add Single() to the end of the LINQ expression, and deal only with that record. That way you make it abundantly clear there is a 1:1 relationship between rows in these tables, no more, no less.

Comment: ^^ That. This isn't about efficiency, it's about *readability* and *maintainability*. Throwing an exception if there's anything other than a single row in that table conveys the expectations and removes all ambiguity - when *the code* says "there's one row in that table, or else...", then you don't need a comment to clarify anything.

Comment: I would say, based on the OP's assertion that there ever will only be 1 row that `.Single()` is the better match to the intent over `.First()`.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer You're right, the answer should be updated to reflect that.

Comment: Good points about `Single()` +1

Comment: I always use .FirstOrDefault and then test for null. Bad?

Comment: @Ewan Not necessarily, but a few things to watch out for. If your first value is nullable (or more specifically if your first value can equal the default value of the type), then a default value can mean 2 different things. Also, if you do `XOrDefault()` and aren't throwing an exception when the value is null then you potentially swallow errors and just get an empty result set when something's gone wrong under the hood, whereas an exception being thrown can alert you to problems.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is is there any advantage storing reference to the `t1Row` in a variable rather having a `foreach` loop?

Not really, but you would gain a lot by removing the inner loop.

The inner loop can be removed like

```
foreach(var currentJob in ttJobHead)
{
    var hdCase = Db.HDCase.Where(hdCase => hdCase.HDCaseNum == currentJob.HDCaseNum).Last();
    if (hdCase != null)
    {
        currentJob.ProjectID = hdCase.ProjectID;
    }
}
```

The advantage of removing the outer loop will at maximum save you some milliseconds, but won't reduce the amount of code, because you then should add a comment, why you only use the "first" element.

But hey, why could the inner loop be removed ? Very easy, for each iteration of the loop you are overwriting the `currentJob.ProjectID` property.

Comment: thanks, but in the inner loop there should only ever be a single match so im not really overriding anything in each iteration.